# Problems with permutations of a string implementation

Tags: c++, stl, runtime-error

I am working on the all permutations of a string problem.  Currently, I am using a list of char to represent a string.  A list of character lists would represent all possible permutations.

The algorithm is very simple.  For each string of length n, you would want to chop off the first letter and find all the permutations of the string of n-l.  Then you would insert the first letter in every place of the smaller string.  Inserting the first letter in causing a runtime exception for me, and I can't seem to figure out where.

Main.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main (void){

    list<char> s;

    s.push_back('f');
    s.push_back('c');
    s.push_back('g');

    list<list<char> > mylist;
    list<char>::iterator vit;
    list<char> myvector;
    mylist = perm(s,mylist);


    for(list<list<char> >::iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it){
        myvector = *it;
        for(vit = myvector.begin(); vit != myvector.end(); ++vit){
            cout << *vit << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;   
}
```

Implementation:

```
list<list <char> > perm(list<char> s, list<list<char> > mylist){
    int n = s.size();

    if(n == 1){
        mylist.push_back(s);
        return mylist;

    }

    else{
        list<char>::iterator vit = s.begin();
        char first = *vit;
        s.erase(vit);        

        list<list<char> > listB = perm(s,mylist);

        for(list<list<char> >::iterator it = listB.begin(); it != listB.end(); ++it){
            list<char> myvector = *it;
            for(list<char>::iterator vit2 = myvector.begin(); vit != myvector.end(); ++vit){
                cout << *vit2 << endl;
                vit2 = myvector.insert(vit2,first);
                cout << *vit2 << endl;
                mylist.push_back(myvector);
                myvector.erase(vit2);
            }
        }

        return mylist;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
                g
                c
                c
                f
                f
```

Then a runtime exception.

Comment: Check the iterators you're using.  You use both vit2 and vit in the inner for loop condition.

Comment: (1) `vit` points into `s`, but you compare it with `myvector.end()` in the inner loop. (2) you erase `vit2` from `myvector`, invalidating it, then use the invalid `vit2` to insert an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr

Just use `std::next_permutation`.